# These two divs won't sit side by side?

Tags: html, css

Here a screenshot of the problem.

[image: Here a screenshot of the problem.]

I have tried all solutions on this side to no avail.

Here is the code i'm using and a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Fx9.png) of the result any help would be appreciated.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <center>
        <h2>How will the 'Savvy Club' help?</h2>
        <br />
    </center>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 pos-left">
                <p>The ‘Savvy Package’ has been created through a thorough knowledge of both Social Media and an understanding of what businesses need. This understanding has been learnt from us going up and dow the country delivering our informative and no holds barred workshop. We soon noticed that we left people inspired yet overwhelmed.</p>
                <br />
                <br />               
                <p>The Savvy club is for businesses who are serious about seeing results through Social Media. We deliver support through webinars and workshops. Our Facebook Group delivers support and information giving members opportunity to share thoughts and experiences.</p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <p><b>Consider the Savvy Club as the helpful, in house digital expert you never had.</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <font face="arial">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-7 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">
            <div class="square">
                <b>Stay On Top of Changes</b>
                <br />
                <p>One of the primary challenges for Social media marketing is that the tools are always changing. We help you keep up with the changes, thanks to a weekly webinars.</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="square">
                <b>Quick Access to Help</b>
                <br />
                <p>Our Savvy Guru’s are on hand to answer any question that comes through the Group giving you the confidence to broadcast with confidence.</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="square">
                <b>Sharpen Your Skills with Training</b>
                <br />
                <p>You’ll have immediate access to all Wisdom Wednesday replays we have delivered via the group, Ideal for binge viewing. We liken it to Netflix for digital strategy.</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="square">
                <b>Support on Content</b>
                <br />
                <p>Knowing what to post and when can sometimes be a problem. Our content calendar briefing will guide you or inspire you on which direction your content should take.</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="square2">
                <b>Someone to speak to</b>
                <br />
                <p>The first year of The Savvy’s delivery there was something missing although you could get questions answered via the group - the opportunity to brain storm and sound out ideas was missing. We have answered this with the second tier of the Savvy Package and called it pro. (Savvy Pro only).</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </font>
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the font tag anymore... use css instead. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: Give them `vertical-align:top` and your done :)

Comment: <font> is obsolete - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Comment: Center tag is also obsolete and b tag should be strong tag - if you are only styling as bold https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b.  As you have used the font tag, you are  not allowed to put block elements inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be aligned side by side they must be in the same row.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <center>
        <h2>How will the 'Savvy Club' help?</h2>
        <br />
    </center>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>The ‘Savvy Package’ has been created through a thorough knowledge of both Social Media and an understanding of what businesses need. This understanding has been learnt from us going up and dow the country delivering our informative and no holds barred workshop. We soon noticed that we left people inspired yet overwhelmed.</p>
                <br />
                <br />               
                <p>The Savvy club is for businesses who are serious about seeing results through Social Media. We deliver support through webinars and workshops. Our Facebook Group delivers support and information giving members opportunity to share thoughts and experiences.</p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <p><b>Consider the Savvy Club as the helpful, in house digital expert you never had.</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="square">
                    <b>Stay On Top of Changes</b>
                    <br />
                    <p>One of the primary challenges for Social media marketing is that the tools are always changing. We help you keep up with the changes, thanks to a weekly webinars.</p>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="square">
                    <b>Quick Access to Help</b>
                    <br />
                    <p>Our Savvy Guru’s are on hand to answer any question that comes through the Group giving you the confidence to broadcast with confidence.</p>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="square">
                    <b>Sharpen Your Skills with Training</b>
                    <br />
                    <p>You’ll have immediate access to all Wisdom Wednesday replays we have delivered via the group, Ideal for binge viewing. We liken it to Netflix for digital strategy.</p>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="square">
                    <b>Support on Content</b>
                    <br />
                    <p>Knowing what to post and when can sometimes be a problem. Our content calendar briefing will guide you or inspire you on which direction your content should take.</p>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="square2">
                    <b>Someone to speak to</b>
                    <br />
                    <p>The first year of The Savvy’s delivery there was something missing although you could get questions answered via the group - the opportunity to brain storm and sound out ideas was missing. We have answered this with the second tier of the Savvy Package and called it pro. (Savvy Pro only).</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```